# Why Django application can't connect to remote MySQL database in Docker container?

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-container

I have `Django` application which works with remote `MySQL` database. I run application with the help of docker container. Unfortunatly in logs of the application I notice error. When I am using my application without Docker it works. Why can't an application running in Docker connect to the database?

```
ERROR Internal Server Error: /main/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/beewifi/main/views/auth.py", line 47, in wifi_login
    zone = Zone.objects.get(identity=params['identity'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1105, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 863, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 420, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 373, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 79, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 373, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 169, in as_sql
    lhs_sql, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 162, in process_lhs
    db_type = self.lhs.output_field.db_type(connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 644, in db_type
    return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 174, in data_types
    if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 53, in supports_microsecond_precision
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 385, in mysql_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 591, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.28.5.17' (110)")
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:2.7.14-jessie
RUN mkdir /db && mkdir /django_logs && mkdir /static && mkdir /photo
ADD server ./server
WORKDIR /my_app
COPY ./requirements.txt /my_app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --timeout 1000 --no-cache-dir
COPY . /my_app
WORKDIR /
RUN bash my_app/nodesource_setup.sh
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /my_app/static
RUN npm install
WORKDIR /my_app
CMD bash run.sh
```

**run.sh:**

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 --workers 3 --timeout 3600 --worker-class gevent --log-level=DEBUG --access-logfile - --error-logfile - --user 0 --group 0 smswifi.wsgi
```

**settings.py:**

```
***
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'XXXX',
        'USER': 'XXXX',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXX',
        'HOST': 'XXX.XX.X.XX',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
***
```

Comment: where you installed the db and is `172.28.5.17` localhost or remote server ?

Comment: @LinPy it's not localhost. Application and database is not in the same servers. `172.28.5.17` is remote MySQL server. I am tring to connect to that remote database. By the way, I ping that ip address from the server where located django application without any problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: check firewall settings for port 3306 maybe ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Since docker runs like as a virtual machine, it is probably looking for the IP address within itself. If you check the database server logs and find that no connections have been rejected or lead to an error, you might want to configure your docker app to use host IP